# XQuery conversion for date to dateTime

Tags: xml, datetime, date, xquery

I have a variable parameter that is formatted to the **date** type in XML.  I need to convert that parameter into the **dateTime** format for another variable to accept my copy operation.  This is being done in BPEL, but the expression builder for XQuery should be the same regardless of the processing language.  Thanks very much for any help.

Answer (score 13):

When $date holds the xs:date value, then

```
$date cast as xs:dateTime
```

will do the job. See the section on [casting](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery/#id-cast) in the [XQuery recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery/) for details

Alternatively, you could pass the xs:date value into the [xs:dateTime constructor function](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/#constructor-functions):

```
xs:dateTime($date)
```

Also there is a special constructor function [fn:dateTime](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/#func-dateTime) that gives control of the time part:

```
fn:dateTime($date, xs:time("17:30:00"))
```

Comment: Thanks but I found the solution on my school message board.  All I needed to do was 
concat ($datevariable, 'T20:30:00')
I still appreciate the help and up-voted the answer for others.

Comment: OK if you know what you are doing, but it is a string operation and as such more vulnerable (e.g. by misspelling) than the corresponding typed operation that I suggested.